# vicent fonts package doesn't work?

Tags: fonts

I tried to compile the example in vicent package  in my pc (windows 8 ,MiKTeX 2.9) and in Sharelatex,Overleaf  after
, without success I get  errors :

In my PC :! Font OT1/vc/m/it/14.4=vcc14 at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.relax The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog.}

Sharelatex :Font OT1/vc/m/sl/12=vcm10 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

relax 
l.7   \modernscriptshape
.
.
.

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font='.

any advise ?

MWE(package example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{vicent}
\begin{document}
\Large\raggedright
\textcursive{This is the `cursive' shape, \textbf{in Bold series}
The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog.}
\textmodernscript{This is the `modern script' shape, \textbf{in Bold
series} The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog.}
\texttwist{This is the `twist' shape \textbf{in Bold series} The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog.}
%example of using low level font selection to get a swash `r'
\raggedleft{\LARGE\fontfamily{vc}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont
James Kilfige\fontshape{its}\selectfont r }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you install the mf-files (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/vicentino/kraml)?

Comment: Yes for example vcaltdri.mf is in C:\Programmes\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\vicentino\kraml

Comment: And all files are in the same directory

Comment: Did you install the package with MikTeX? If not, do it that way. If so, you may need to manually force an update of the font mapping files as this is a known problem with MikTeX. (I don't use MikTeX, but if you search a bit, you should find details & instructions for doing this.)

Comment: The package is installed and I update , I tried in sharelatex, Overleaf I get  the same error !

Comment: Where did you get the package? According to the TeX catalogue, it isn't part of any distribution.

Comment: The mf files should be in fonts/source/vicentino. Don't forget to update the FNDB (in miktex settings (admin) after you moved them.